# Elasticsearch - Specify parameter in url not recognized

Tags: rest, http, elasticsearch, get, request

I'm new to elasticsearch and actually I'm trying to retrieve some data from elastic using the REST API.

```
URL = "http://localhost:9200/houses*/_search"

filter_path = 'hits.hits._source'
city = "Las Vegas"
size = 10
sort = 'review_count:desc'
PARAMS = {'filter_path': filter_path, 'city': city  'size': size, 'sort': sort}

print(requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS).text)
request = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)

data = request.json()
```

I'm getting the following error saying that city is not recognized as paramater but it's one one my data field.

```
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'request [/houses*/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [city]'}], 'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'request [/houses*/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [city]'}, 'status': 400}
```

I will be glad if you figure out why it's not working :)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `city` parameter. If you want to send a query in your URL you need to do it via the [`q` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search-api-query-params), like this:

```
filter_path = 'hits.hits._source'
query = 'city:"Las Vegas"'
size = 10
sort = 'review_count:desc'
PARAMS = {'filter_path': filter_path, 'q': query  'size': size, 'sort': sort}
```

The rest looks fine and should work.

Comment: Thanks it's finally working, I appreciate your help :)